# React-Native expo-google-drive-api-wrapper not uploading base64 images

Tags: react-native, google-drive-api, expo

1. I pick an image using ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'. Said image is stored in `base64Ref`
2. If I send the file to Google Drive using `b64 = false` the upload works fine.
3. If I use `b64 = true` the file is never sent. All The info I can get is:

response

```js
{
  "type": "default",
  "status": 400,
  "ok": false,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {
    "map": {
        "content-type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
          "date": "Tue, 21 Dec 2021 20:03:22 GMT",
          "server": "UploadServer",
          "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"",
          "content-length": "25",
          "x-guploader-uploadid": "ADPycdsJHDbYYbvBnEgBfKrSEN6vSN2MswfCUxxJeSc6CFmQZpeWx43budeb9Fumt-bWmja5j3mjGNwAfDEn4bosjcQ"
    }
},
  "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
  "bodyUsed": false,
  "_bodyInit": {
    "_data": {
        "size": 25,
          "offset": 0,
          "blobId": "d811ac9c-431d-4582-8de4-d31adb93ca8f",
          "__collector": {}
    }
},
    "_bodyBlob": {
    "_data": {
        "size": 25,
          "offset": 0,
          "blobId": "d811ac9c-431d-4582-8de4-d31adb93ca8f",
          "__collector": {}
    }
}
```

**This is the code**

```js
const b64 = false;

Drive.files.createFileMultipart(
  "data:image/png;base64,"+base64Ref.current,
  "image/png", {
      parents: ["root"],
      name: "MyImage.png"
  },
  b64)
  .then((response) => {
      let q = response;
      console.log("response");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(q));
  })
```

Comment: Have you tried consulting the documentation? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#node.js

Comment: @DaImTo Well, besides specifying an extension for the file name I don't see anything else (Tried that, didn't work). Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance